# Custom tag or custom attributes

Tags: node.js, express, pug, mustache

I would like to know the possibility to develop custom html tags or custom html attributes to node.js , rather in jade, html or another html template enginer. I was looking at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and I don't realize any example that accomplish it, either [Cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) as well. My goal is to make some components to easily usage in any kind of popular html engines. Any direction will be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean with "custom html tags"? something like [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) from angular.js?

Comment: Yeah, custom attributes like "ng-model" from AngularJS or custom tag like: "<mytag>hello</mytag>.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is just a webserver, You need something to parse the custom tags, so its either the template engine that will convert it to valid html, or client side with JavaScript (aka AngularJS directives)

Comment: I know that I mean I wonder to know how to handle custom attributes, which parse engine or something to intercept a jade template or an html one.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own [filter](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#filters) similar to the example

```
body
  :markdown
    Woah! jade _and_ markdown, very **cool**
    we can even link to [stuff](http://google.com)
```

That would give you

```
<body>
  <p>Woah! jade <em>and</em> markdown, very <strong>cool</strong> we can even 
    link to <a href="http://google.com">stuff</a>
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks zeMirco, maybe I will something like document.getElementById(...).setdata.<valeu> to retrieve. I would like to know some parse engine easily to implement even if you use HTML or jade to express.